# Trouble calling R function from Python with rpy2

Tags: python, r, rpy2, cbind

I am trying to use rpy2 to call the R package MatchIt. I am having difficulty seeing the outcome of the matched pairs from the $match.matrix. Here is the R code I am trying to execute in python.

```
matched <- cbind(lalonde[row.names(foo$match.matrix),"re78"],lalonde[foo$match.matrix,"re78"])
```

Here is my python code:

```
import readline
import rpy2.robjects
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
from rpy2 import robjects as ro

import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import ttest_ind
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series,DataFrame

pandas2ri.activate()
R = ro.r
MatchIt = importr('MatchIt')
base = importr('base')

df = R('lalonde')
lalonde = pandas2ri.py2ri(df)
formula = 'treat ~ age + educ + black + hispan + married + nodegree + re74 + re75'

foo = MatchIt.matchit(formula = R(formula),
                               data = lalonde,
                               method = R('"nearest"'),
                               ratio = 1)

matched = \
base.cbind(lalonde.rx[base.row_names(foo.rx2('match.matrix')),"re78"], 
       lalonde.rx[foo.rx2('match.matrix'),"re78"])
```

This chunk runs :

```
lalonde.rx(base.row_names(foo.rx2('match.matrix')),
       "re78")
```

but this chunk

```
lalonde.rx[foo.rx2('match.matrix'),"re78"].
```

returns an error of:

```
ValueError: The first parameter must be a tuple.
```

The output of

```
cbind(lalonde[row.names(foo$match.matrix),"re78"], lalonde[foo$match.matrix,"re78"])
```

should be a dataframe which matches the row names and cell values of foo$match.matrix with the values of "re78" in the lalonde dataframe

Comment: Where does `lalonde` or `foo` derive? And what type of objects are they? Your code does not show their assignment

Comment: lalonde is a data frame which is used in the MatchIt documentation. foo is the output of the matchit() function. foo$match.matrix is an: n1× ratio matrix where:
– the row names represent the names of the treatment units (which match the row
names of the data frame specified in data).
– each column stores the name(s) of the control unit(s) matched to the treatment
unit of that row. For example, when the ratio input for nearest neighbor or
optimal matching is specified as 3, the three columns of match.matrix represent
the three control units matched to one treatment unit).

Comment: You need to first load `lalonde` data frame (see page 10 of the PDF manual). Try `MatchIt.data(lalonde)`. Interesting Python didn't complain about this unqualified and unassigned object.

Comment: Sorry I didn't not include the entire script, but I have loaded the lalonde data frame and still get this error.

Answer (score 2):

Here `lalonde` is defined elsewhere (but thanks to @Parfait's question we know that this is a data frame). Now you'll have to break down your one-liner triggering the error to pinpoint the exact place of trouble (and we can't do that for you - the thing about self-contained and reproducible examples is that they are helping us help you).

```
matched = \
base.cbind(lalonde[base.row_names(foo.rx2('match.matrix')),"re78"], 
           lalonde[foo.rx2('match.matrix'),"re78"])
```

Is this breaking with the first subset of `lalonde` ?

```
lalonde[base.row_names(foo.rx2('match.matrix')),"re78"]
```

Since `type(lalonde)` is `rpy2.robjects.vectors.DataFrame` this is an R/rpy2 data frame. Extracting a subset like one would do it in R can be achieved with `.rx` (as in **r**-style e**x**traction - see http://rpy2.readthedocs.io/en/version_2.8.x/vector.html#extracting-r-style
).

```
lalonde.rx(base.row_names(foo.rx2('match.matrix')),
           "re78")
```

It is important to understand what is happening with this call. By default the elements to extract in each direction of the data structure (here rows and columns of the data frame respectively) must be R vectors (vector of names, or vector of one-offset index integers) or a Python data structure that the conversion mechanism can translate into an R vector (of names or integers). `base.row_names` will return the row names (and that's a vector of names) but `foo.rx2('match.matrix')` might be something else.

Here `type(foo.rx2('match.matrix'))` is indicating that this is a matrix. Using matrices can be used be used to cherry pick cells in an R array, but in that case there can only be one parameter for the extraction... and we presently have two (the second is `"re78"`).

Since the first column of that `match.matrix` contains the indices (row numbers) in `lalonde`, the following should be what you want:

```
matched = \
base.cbind(lalonde.rx[base.row_names(foo.rx2('match.matrix')),"re78"], 
           lalonde.rx[foo.rx2('match.matrix').rx(True, 1),"re78"])
```

Comment: type(lalonde) = rpy2.robjects.vectors.DataFrame

Comment: @clfrazier : continued the answer accordingly

Comment: Thank you very helpful. That chunk now runs, however when updating the entire line it still get an error. I have updated my question.

Comment: type(foo.rx2('match.matrix')) = rpy2.robjects.vectors.Matrix

​

Comment: lalonde.nrow == foo.rx2('match.matrix').nrow is False. foo.rx2('match.matrix') returns a subset of lalonde. The row names of foo.rx2('match.matrix') correspond to the row names of lalonde and the first column in foo.rx2('match.matrix') also is corresponds to an index of lalonde.  foo.rx2('match.matrix') matches rows of similar observations - the row name being the treated observation and the first column being the control observation

Comment: Ok. The code in the answer should still work even if `lalonde.nrow == foo.rx2('match.matrix').nrow` since the fist column (`foo.rx2('match.matrix').rx(True, 1)`) corresponds to indices (row numbers) in `lalonde`).